# Using Spring Cloud Vault and ConfigData API with multiple profile files

Tags: spring-vault

I have 5 profiles for my Spring Boot application

```
application.yml
application-prod.yml
application-stg.yml
application-dev.yml
application-local.yml
```

One default config and 4 for different environments.

`application.yml` looks like this

```
spring:
  cloud:
  vault:
    enabled: ${VAULT_ENABLED:false}
    host: ${VAULT_HOST}
    port: ${VAULT_PORT}
    authentication: aws_iam
    aws-iam:
      role: ${VAULT_POLICY}
      server-name: ${VAULT_HOST}
    kv:
      backend: kv
      enabled: true
```

Some of the properties are provided by the host in the environment variables.
To support local development I am overriding `authentication` in `local` profile like this

```
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: true
      authentication: token
      token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}
```

Now the question is how to import config correctly?
If I will do `spring.config.import: "vault:"` in `application.yml` it will fail while running with `local` profile. As ConfigData API will try to resolve `vault` properties immediately after default profile is processed (but auth info not yet loaded). But as `local` profile is supposed to use different auth method, it cannot access Vault and fails.

Another question is how to disable Vault in some cases? I could do `spring.cloud.vault.enabled=false`, but this again would cause failure as ConfigData cannot resolve `vault:`.

Yes I could use legacy bootstrap mode which would work fine for my scenario, but in the longer run wouldn't be ideal...

Only thing that comes on my mind is to create additional profile, eg `vault` which would be loaded as a last one. With enabling / disabling this profile I could control if config from Vault is imported or not...

Any other ideas?

Comment: About disable vault mode, did you try to use bootstrap.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem, but we have found a workaround overriding the default import order of Spring Boot by importing also the profile-specific configuration files explicitly using `spring.config.import` in `application.yml` like this:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${STAGE:local}
  config:
    import:
    - optional:classpath:application-${STAGE:local}.yml
    - vault://secret/our-secret
```

Note that the `STAGE` environment variable corresponds to the profile used per stage. We made the import of the profile-specific configuration file optional, as we don't have a dedicated file for every stage.

By providing the import for the profile-specific configuration files explicitly before the vault config, we can override the default vault settings before the vault is accessed.

Still, this approach feels a bit awkward, but it's the only way so far we found to work around the issue, so better solutions would be appreciated.